# Olfactory system in biomedical engineering domain?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, control-theory

Is there any modeling for Olfactory system in biomedical engineering?‌, or any circuit form of these as like as following for aorta?

[image: This figure]

if we couldn't provide a model, which domain is good for it?